# Table of Contents breaks file running

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a file, which works fine, if there is no table of contents, however, while trying to compile this file with added  `\tableofcontents` command, compiler tells me:

> myfile.toc 2 LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

What's the solution?

edited:

I've just found that `\tableofcontents` are not in good relations with section's renewing:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}%
    {\baselineskip} 
    {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}        
   }%
   \makeatother
```

If I remove this renewing, `\tableofcontents` makes no problem. 
So this probably makes the problem clear?

Comment: Hard to say given that information. Probably the `.toc` file is corrupt. Try removing `myfile.aux` and `myfile.toc` and see if that gets LaTeX back in sync.

Comment: it might help if that were to appear as part of a miminal example.  cutting and pasting from your post, i get an error, but not the missing item one.  i assume i've made a copying error.  but what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

Please make a minimal example that demonstrates the problem to make it easier for you I'm putting this as an answer rather than a comment so I can add a formatted example

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{
    \@startsection
        {section}{1}{0mm}
    {\baselineskip}%
    {\baselineskip} 
    {\fontsize{14}{14}\centering\bfseries\MakeUppercase}        
   }%
   \makeatother 

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{aaaaa}

asa

\section{bbbb}

\end{document}
```

this document runs without error, please edit your question to add a version of this example that does demonstrate the problem.